# Sort dataset columns by num, then factors

Tags: r, dataset

Hi I have a dataset that I have transformed to only nums and factors,
I want to separate the factors columns from the numerical columns.
I'm new to coding and its probably very simple but I've looked around and I'm very thankful if anyone could help

```
'data.frame':   400 obs. of  25 variables:
 $ age           : num  48 7 62 48 51 60 68 24 52 53 ...
 $ bp            : num  80 50 80 70 80 90 70 76 100 90 ...
 $ sg            : num  1.02 1.02 1.01 1 1.01 ...
 $ al            : num  1 4 2 4 2 3 0 2 3 2 ...
 $ su            : num  0 0 3 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 ...
 $ rbc           : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","0": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ pc            : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","0": 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ pcc           : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","0": 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 ...
 $ ba            : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","0": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ bgr           : num  121 148 423 117 106 74 100 410 138 70 ...
 $ bu            : num  36 18 53 56 26 25 54 31 60 107 ...
 $ sc            : num  1.2 0.8 1.8 3.8 1.4 1.1 24 1.1 1.9 7.2 ...
 $ sod           : num  137 137 137 111 137 142 104 137 137 114 ...
 $ pot           : num  4 4 4 2.5 4 3.2 4 4 4 3.7 ...
 $ hemo          : num  15.4 11.3 9.6 11.2 11.6 12.2 12.4 12.4 10.8 9.5 ...
 $ pcv           : num  44 38 31 32 35 39 36 44 33 29 ...
 $ wc            : num  7800 6000 7500 6700 7300 ...
 $ rc            : num  5.2 4 4 3.9 4.6 4.4 4 5 4 3.7 ...
 $ htn           : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","0": 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 ...
 $ dm            : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","0": 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ cad           : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","0": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ appet         : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","0": 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 ...
 $ pe            : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","0": 2 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 2 ...
 $ ane           : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","0": 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 ...
 $ classification: Factor w/ 2 levels "1","0": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a boolean vector `fac` with information which is factor, then `cbind` subsets. *Example:*

```
dat
#   F1 N2 N1 F2 N3 F3 N4 F4
# 1  A  4  1  D  7  G 10  J
# 2  B  5  2  E  8  H 11  K
# 3  C  6  3  F  9  I 12  L

fac <- sapply(dat, is.factor)
cbind(dat[!fac], dat[fac])
#   N2 N1 N3 N4 F1 F2 F3 F4
# 1  4  1  7 10  A  D  G  J
# 2  5  2  8 11  B  E  H  K
# 3  6  3  9 12  C  F  I  L
```

---

*Data*

```
dat <- structure(list(F1 = structure(1:3, levels = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
    N2 = 4:6, N1 = 1:3, F2 = structure(1:3, levels = c("D", "E", 
    "F"), class = "factor"), N3 = 7:9, F3 = structure(1:3, levels = c("G", 
    "H", "I"), class = "factor"), N4 = 10:12, F4 = structure(1:3, levels = c("J", 
    "K", "L"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```